# How to install bytestring formatters for built-in types in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I am trying to port Python2 protocol code to Python3. How do I get bytestring formatters for built-in types? In Python2, we could do:

```
>>> b'%s' % None
'None'
>>> b'%s' % 15
'15'
>>> b'%s' % []
'[]'
```

The same code in Python3 gives:

```
>>> b'%s' % None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %b requires bytes, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'NoneType'
>>> b'%s' % 15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %b requires bytes, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'int'
>>> b'%s' % []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %b requires bytes, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'list'
```

How do I install the standard bytestring formatters for built-in types?

Comment: It requires `bytes` as an argument, basically. Just provide it with `bytes`, something like `str(None).encode("ascii")` would work

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: @juanpa I understand that we could write our own bytestring encoder or build one out of existing builtins. Wouldn't this get cumbersome though for things like b'%s, %s:%s' % (x, y, z)?

Comment: @toyota Thank you for providing a syntax reference. Are you saying there's a syntax error? I rather see a `TypeError` indicating missing formatters.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385108/how-do-i-achieve-sprintf-style-formatting-for-bytes-objects-in-python-3 , though there were no good answers there.

Comment: You aren't writing an encoder, you are simply being explicit about the encoding used. The whole point of Python 3 was to separate text from bytes to *force* you to be explicit about this. You are basically wanting to do *text manipulation here*, so you can just start with text (i.e. with `str` not `bytes`), do the interpolation, and then choose the encoding on the final result, if you don't want to choose the encoding in the intermediate pieces.

Comment: @BoppreH there is a good answer, which is to *be explicit about the encoding when converting from text to bytes*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not trying to convert unicodes to bytes. I'm trying to avoid conversion in the first place, by generating bytes directly, as one does in Python 2 or C. All of my program's I/O and processing is in bytes. There's never a need for a unicode object. Sure, there can be unicode characters encoded in the bytes somehow, but my program shouldn't care how. It's a bug if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"bytestring formatters for built-in types" aren't a thing in Python 3. [Textual data is handled at a higher level by default in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), and that includes object representations.

Instead, you can explicitly encode a string representation of an object into bytes, for example:

```
>>> ('%s' % None).encode('ascii')
b'None'
```

All builtin Python types are encodeable as ASCII, though the data they contain might not be, for example:

```
>>> L = []
>>> ('%s' % L).encode('ascii')
b'[]'
>>> L.append('café ∀ ')
>>> ('%s' % L).encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In that case, you can specify a different encoding, for example UTF-8:

```
>>> ('%s' % L).encode('utf-8')
b"['caf\xc3\xa9 \xe2\x88\x80 \xf0\x9f\x91\x8d']"
```

Or if the result is going to be used in a Python context, you could use the [`ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) conversion, `%a`:

```
>>> ('%a' % L).encode('ascii')
b"['caf\\xe9 \\u2200 \\U0001f44d']"
```

This shows an escape sequence for all non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes, `%a` is what I was looking for. In particular for things like `b"%a" % None`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use f-strings and encode them:

```py
x = None
y = 15
z = []
print(f'{x}, {y}:{z}'.encode())
```

Output:

```
b'None, 15:[]'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the conversions back and forth don't always do what we expect. For example, `f'{"≥".encode()}'` is not the same as `"≥".encode().decode()`. These sorts of issues are much less likely if everything stays in bytes. `(b"%s" % "≥".encode()).decode()` works as we expect because `%` does not try to convert to unicode when everything is in bytes.

Comment: @personal_cloud Did you misread it? Mark's recommending encoding the whole f-string, not fields inside the f-string. I.e. `f'{"≥"}'.encode().decode() == "≥"`.